# Rails error after updating gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

After running `gem update`, I get the following error, when I try to start rails:

```
$ rails s
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:238:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime)
for ["actionpack-3.2.12", "railties-3.2.12"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-
ssl-1.3.3", "railties-3.2.12"] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:254:in `block in activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:253:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:253:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:254:in `block in activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:253:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:253:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone please help me, what this means and how to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't activate rack (~> 1.4.0, runtime) already activated rack-1.5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485219/cant-activate-rack-1-4-0-runtime-already-activated-rack-1-5-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must run it using bundler.

```
$ bundle exec rails s
```

Otherwise, you need to uninstall the rack version 1.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

delete Gemfile.lock

then run

```
$> bundle install
```

Comment: That was the more elegant solution which worked for me.  In reality it is all about those versions locked there.