# Rails Cannot Create Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i try to create a site in Ruby on Rails i get following error

anyone ?

$rails new /var/www/vhosts/sales/ruby/blog

```
  /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:233:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.13", "railties-3.2.13"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-ssl-1.3.3", "ra
ilties-3.2.13"] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
        from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Comment: `rails new <appname>` is how you create an app in Rails 3.

Comment: Can you do ruby -v and rails -v and tell us your versions?

Comment: ruby -v returns 
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: rails -v return following error

/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:233:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.13", "railties-3.2.13"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-ssl-1.3.3", "ra
ilties-3.2.13"] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/sit

Comment: Do you have rails installed?

Comment: how do i check (this my first try with ruby on rails) ?

Comment: this seems to be the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485219/cant-activate-rack-1-4-0-runtime-already-activated-rack-1-5-0

Comment: thansk for pointing i got it solved via "gem uninstall rack"

Answer (score 1):

Reason was there was a conflict between two rack versions so i had uninstall the unrealted version via

```
gem uninstall rack
```

did the trick

Answer (score 1):

You must `cd` first on what `directory` you want to create a `new project`.

If you're inside that directory you can now type a `rails new YOUR_APP_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

rails new demo

Replace demo with an actual path or project name.

Comment: @user1179459: you may have to be a bit more specific with 'that doesn't work'.

Comment: i have edited the question, i mean i still get the same error